# Command not found when trying to run a script with sudo while configuring Arduino

Tags: command-line, software-installation, arduino

I'm working on 16.04 and trying to setup the Arduino IDE for use with a Genuino 101. I have the IDE installed, v 1.8.2, in my home folder. It compiles sketches and picks up the board serial number as well as other details correctly. According to the Arduino site, one needs to execute

```
sudo ~/.arduino15/packages/Intel/tools/arduino101load/1.6.4+1.18/scripts/create_dfu_udev_rule
```

inside a shell to gain upload permissions.

When I execute this through the terminal I get the error message

```
sudo: /home/16737547/.arduino15/packages/Intel/tools/arduino101load/1.6.4+1.18/scripts/create_dfu_udev_rule: command not found
```

Is this command looking for v 1.6.4 of the IDE? I have tried to modify the command to

```
sudo ~/.arduino15/packages/Intel/tools/arduino101load/1.8.2+1.18/scripts/create_dfu_udev_rule
```

but it did not resolve the error message.

Comment: that error is thrown by `sudo` when the file does not have execute permission. If the file exists, you may fix the problem by running `chmod u+x ~/.arduino/packages/Intel/tools/arduino101load/1.6.4+1.18/scripts/create_dfu_udev_rule` and then repeat the command. You must check that the file exists though! For information, run `ls -l  ~/.arduino/packages/Intel/tools/arduino101load/1.6.4+1.18/scripts/create_dfu_udev_rule`

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this:

1. Open a terminal with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>
2. Make the file executable with:

   ```
   chmod u+x ~/.arduino15/packages/Intel/tools/arduino101load/1.6.4+1.18/scripts/create_dfu_udev_rule
   ```
3. Type the command and press <kbd>enter</kbd>

   ```
   sudo ~/.arduino15/packages/Intel/tools/arduino101load/1.6.4+1.18/scripts/create_dfu_udev_rule
   ```